# Correcting spelling errors in OCR texts

Tags: natural-language, optical-character-recognition

### Situation

- customer contracts available as scanned images were **turned into text files using OCR software**
- the resulting texts contain **spelling errors** that occurred during OCR, e.g. words like "useful" were mistaken as "u***5***eful"

### Question

What are current best practices for correcting these OCR spelling errors as a post-processing step?

1. for standard vocabularies, i.e. correcting *common* words
2. for specific vocabularies, i.e. correcting specific product names, customer names, special terms etc.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The best solution would probably be to re-OCR the documents using a better OCR, ideally with a language model that is specifically tuned for the domain of the documents.

Otherwise, you can use a spell-checker with an additional custom vocabulary, there are several Python packages for that, e.g., [*pyspelling*](https://pypi.org/project/pyspelling/) has an interface for both Hunspell and Aspell. The advantage of existing spell-checkers is that they have optimized algorithms for retrieving correct similar words. The disadvantage is that they treat all edits equally.

To get around this, you can get more spell-checker suggestions than you would normally display to a user and re-score them. The simplest way is designing a weighted edit distance where errors that are frequent in your data would get a low cost (e.g., substituting `s` and `5` should be a cheap operation). There are also several Python packages for that, [*weighted-levenshtein*](https://pypi.org/project/weighted-levenshtein/) should be pretty fast. If you want a really fancy solution, you can re-score the suggestions using a language model.